# Hyper-v VM No Internet Connection with Default Switch

Tags: windows, wifi, hyper-v, nat

Posting because I lost 4 hours on this problem and Googling didn't help - solution below.

I have Hyper-V running on Windows 11 with a Windows 11 VM. The VM has no internet connection.

It *seems* like the DHCP server isn't issuing an IP address to my VM.

Every configuration setting looks right.

The Hyper-V configuration is standard! I'm using the Default Switch hosting NAT. It's always worked before. It was working minutes earlier when the host laptop was connected to a different Wi-Fi network.

Answer (score 1):

It took 4 hours but the clue was "It was working minutes earlier when the host laptop was connected to a different Wi-Fi network."

There was something different in the network I'd joined.

The new network has:

1. A router with gateway 192.168.1.1
2. Google Home Wi-Fi (3 devices creating a Wi-Fi Mesh so that I have a strong signal throughout the house) with gateway 192.168.86.1

`ipconfig` on the VM reported:

```
Ethernet adapter Ethernet 3:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : mshome.net
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::18da:ec53:3953:c870%6
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.86.27
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.80.1
```

**Changing Google Home Wi-Fi to use Router LAN address 192.168.2.1 and a matching DHCP address pool fixed it.**

It took a couple of minutes for the Wi-Fi mesh to be re-established but when it had finished, the VM immediately connected with a fast connection. Here's the Google Nest help article that helped me: https://support.google.com/googlenest/answer/7571856

Avoid the temptation to change to a bridged external network switch! Avoid the temptation to change any of the VM's networking config.